# Is delaying the graduation out of beta damaging to Acad.SE?

Tags: discussion

Over the last few days, we have had rapid closing votes on [a question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/how-to-deal-with-the-frustration-of-doing-phd-at-a-low-ranked-university), followed by reopening. Even in questions which are ostensibly off-topic, but not on careful thought ([example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/how-to-deal-with-the-frustration-of-doing-phd-at-a-low-ranked-university)), the closing votes have been dealt swiftly.

For a site like ours with [4 excellent](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) grades and 1 Okay grade, is delaying the graduation out of beta harmful? More users with fewer points may have the privileges and there is the possibility of handling them without care.

For now, we could appeal to all for sincere consideration before downvoting or closing. We would want to be welcoming to new users and their questions. We also do not want to shuttle back and forth between closing and reopening.

Comment: I am down voting because I disagree, but I think this is an important question.

Comment: I guess "Disagree" means your answer is a 'No'. The meta definition is confusing at times.

Comment: correct, my answer is No.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the downvoting/closing delaying graduation out of beta?

Comment: Quick closures are a good sign. Toggling like that says you should probably be taking advantage of meta to discuss things sooner/more; something that the beta period should be used to educate your users on.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question, no, I do not think so. The goal of any SE site is to increase the audience and hopefully maintain an active community. The fact that we're having disagreements as to how to deal with questions is probably a sign of a healthy, growing community, which is good. The fact you're asking about it here is a sign that you guys know how to handle it, which is even better :) We *want* more non-diamond mods, and we want everyone to know how to manage the site.

The only constructive criticism I have is that non-diamond mods (and diamond mods as well, myself included) should search the meta to be familiar with decisions already made by the community so that issues don't arise repeatedly.

On a related note, a reminder to everyone: Please don't ask about graduation from beta. It will happen when it happens. We have no control over it; it's purely a decision by the Stack Exchange team. So far as I can tell using my Super Sekrit Mod Powers™, we're doing great.

Comment: As a comment about searching beta: I agree that it is useful to run hrough and look at what has been discussed over time, however, at some point it would be sueful to start assembling certain information in some form of "digest" wiki posts. This has been done on TeX.sx where I also ry to ptovide some input. having such posts to refer to in comments etc. may help the site be more consistent.

Comment: @PeterJansson - I was wondering about that, and I was going to ask other site mods how they do it. Can you share a link? I'd love to see how you did that.

Comment: Sure. Here is one on welcome messages for starters: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/430/19384 and one on often asked questions: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419/19384 As I see it the needs here are slightly different but outlining what we expect and providing snippets of standard answers to improve posts can be very useful.

Comment: @PeterJansson - Cool, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

If anything I think it suggests that we are NOT ready to graduate. We need to learn how to discuss closing/reopening/tagging/editing etc within the confines and tools we have.

I personally think we vote to close way too quickly. I would like to see more discussion about closing gray area questions. I think this could happen in either the comments, chat or meta, but right now we are not doing it and not encouraging new users.

Comment: While I agree with your second point (too quick to vote to close), I think that's irrelevant to the main question.